# Sequelize many-to-many self reference

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get one of the association [examples](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) from sequelize working properly and it doesn't seem to be setting up the join table correctly. In the example we have one model called Person and then a many-to-many self-reference for a Person's children. Code:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://root@localhost/database_bug');

var Person = sequelize.define('Person', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

Person.belongsToMany(Person, { as: 'Children', through: 'PersonChildren' });

Person.sequelize.sync({force:true}).then(function() {
  Person.build({ name: 'John Doe' }).save().then(function(father) {
    Person.build({ name: 'Jane Doe' }).save().then(function(daughter) {
      father.addChild(daughter);
    });
  });
});
```

But when I look at my tables in postgres I feel like a column is missing on the auto-generated join table.

```
            List of relations
 Schema |      Name      |   Type   | Owner 
--------+----------------+----------+-------
 public | People         | table    | root
 public | People_id_seq  | sequence | root
 public | PersonChildren | table    | root

                                    Table "public.People"
  Column   |           Type           |                       Modifiers                       
-----------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                  | not null default nextval('"People_id_seq"'::regclass)
 name      | character varying(255)   | not null
 createdAt | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updatedAt | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "People_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""PersonChildren"" CONSTRAINT "PersonChildren_PersonId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("PersonId") REFERENCES "People"(id)

          Table "public.PersonChildren"
  Column   |           Type           | Modifiers 
-----------+--------------------------+-----------
 createdAt | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updatedAt | timestamp with time zone | not null
 PersonId  | integer                  | not null
Indexes:
    "PersonChildren_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("PersonId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "PersonChildren_PersonId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("PersonId") REFERENCES "People"(id)
```

`PersonChildren` needs a column called `ChildId` or something along those lines to link a Person to its Child.

People table:

```
database_bug=# SELECT * FROM "People";
 id |   name   |         createdAt          |         updatedAt          
----+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | John Doe | 2015-02-06 09:36:44.975-08 | 2015-02-06 09:36:44.975-08
  2 | Jane Doe | 2015-02-06 09:36:44.985-08 | 2015-02-06 09:36:44.985-08
```

Weirder still, I select to make sure `daughter` was added as a child to `father`:

```
database_bug=# SELECT * from "PersonChildren";
         createdAt          |         updatedAt          | PersonId 
----------------------------+----------------------------+----------
 2015-02-06 09:36:44.997-08 | 2015-02-06 09:36:44.997-08 |        2
```

But PersonId is 2, not 1. The `father` was supposed to add the `daughter`, not the other way around.

Any ideas how to get this association working?

Comment: from where this `addChild` function coming ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like the example in the documentation is wrong. To be fair they did say must use `hasMany` but then showed an example using `belongsToMany`.

I changed `belongsToMany` to `hasMany` and it looks like we are good to go:

```
          Table "public.PersonChildren"
  Column   |           Type           | Modifiers 
-----------+--------------------------+-----------
 createdAt | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updatedAt | timestamp with time zone | not null
 PersonId  | integer                  | not null
 ChildId   | integer                  | not null

database_bug=# select * from "PersonChildren";
         createdAt          |         updatedAt          | PersonId | ChildId 
----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+---------
 2015-02-06 10:04:21.624-08 | 2015-02-06 10:04:21.624-08 |        1 |       2
```

Now I can do father.getChildren() and the promise will return a list of children.

Comment: This problem was fixed in Sequelize. They now recommend you use `.belongsToMany` when creating a many-to-many self reference.

Comment: Do you have an example of belongsToMany when creating a many-to-many self reference?